# Why does Alt+F1 lock the computer, and how do I get back the old behavior?

Tags: shortcut-keys

Normally when I press Alt+F1, Ubuntu 18.04 displays my open applications and a search bar to access all installed software. I use this feature a lot, but sometimes (such as right now), all of a sudden Alt+F1 locks the computer instead.

How can I get back the old behavior, and what happened,

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an 'F-lock' key or something similar that you may have accidentally pressed? It sounds like the hardware intercepts the keystroke before the OS...